# How can tFileList output be sent to a file in Talend?

Tags: talend

I want to connect the list of files returned by tFileList to a file. Does not allow me to connect it to a tFileOutputDelimited component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you can do is below - tfilelist gives option to iterate and you can connect it to tFixedFlowInput. in tFixedFlowInput you can create a schema column say filename with expression as

```
filename = ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))
```

assuming tFileList_1 is the name of tFileList component.
From tFixedFlowInput you can connect to tFileOutputDelimited and write to file. Make sure to use append option of tFileOutputDelimited as else it will keep overwriting data in each iteration.

```
tFileList--->(iterate)tFixedFlowInput------>(rowmain)------->tFileOutputDelimited
```